# Explanation of network interdiction in layman terms

Tags: computer-engineering, networking

I am trying to understand network interdiction. I have read these papers, but it is still hard to get a clear understanding of what it exactly means:

1. [Blind Network Interdiction Strategies - A Learning Approach](http://www.buehrer.ece.vt.edu/papers/BlindNetworkInterdiction.pdf)
2. [Network interdiction – models, applications, unexplored directions](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2012/04_2012.pdf)

Could someone explain it to me in layman's terms, using minimal technical language?

Answer (score 3):

The first paragraph from [your second reference](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2012/04_2012.pdf) seems pretty clear.  The first sentence states that

> Network interdiction is the monitoring or halting of an adversary’s activity on a network.

Your confusion probably arrises from thinking of the word 'network' in too specific a way.  To understand this more clearly, it is probably best to consider a military example, which seems to be [the most common usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdiction) for the term.

The map below shows the presence of ISIS in Iraq and Syria during 2014.  The territory under their control can be thought of as a network.  The major cities and towns can be thought of as nodes (vertices), and the connections between them (mostly roads in this case) can be though of as links (edges).  The US military probably has the goal of **network flow interdiction** which seeks to disrupt the flow of goods through the network in the most effective way possible.  This would prevent the various territories under ISIS control from being able to transport arms, food, and other goods to each other.  Trying to identify the most effective way to do so is one of the problems that network interdiction tries to solve.

[image]

Comment: I do have an understanding of network interdiction. I just do not know how to put it in simpler words. What you provided me is an example. I only need explanation. If you can, then please do so. Otherwise, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Master It is expressed in words in the first paragraph of your second reference, which I have quoted in my answer.  If that isn't simple enough for you then perhaps you need to contact [Randall Munroe](https://xkcd.com/thing-explainer/). ;)